# correlation coefficient in pandas (pearson)

Tags: regression, correlation, r-squared, rms, pandas

I have divided my data into training and testing, and I am outputting the error metrics on the testing data. This is what I get:

```
R^2: 0.999
Adj R^2: 0.99
RMSE: 0.003
MSE: 0.000
MAE: 0.003
MAPE: 0.001
Correlation between actual and predicted: 1.000
```

I am using panda's correlation coefficient (pearson) to identify the correlation between the actual values and the predicted ones by the model. As I am inserting the predicted values as columns into my dataset, I am using pandas' correlation coefficient to determine the correlation between two columns.

My question is that how do I get a correlation of 1 while RMSE being greater than 0, and R^2 being less than 1?

Comment: This is almost certainly the same problem as in your last question - rounding.

Comment: I would plot the data always. This could be extremely well behaved  data — or something not so good, like a massive outlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the details are a tiny bit different, so in case it's not a duplicate:

Recall that $R^2$ is the square of the correlation coefficient $r$. So if $r$ = 0.9996, then $R^2$ ~ 0.9992. Rounding those values to 3 decimal places will give you an $r$ of 1.000 and an $R^2$ of 0.999.